# If $\sin B = −1/2$ with $B$ in QIII, find $\cos B/2$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

For the following, assume that all the given angles are in simplest form, so that if A is in QIV you may assume that 270° < A < 360°.

If $\sin B = −1/2$ with B in QIII, find $\cos B/2$

Here's my attempt. Am I correct? $ -sqrt((-sqrt(3)+2)/4)$

$ -\sqrt{\frac{-\sqrt3+2}4}$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-sqrt%28%28-sqrt%283%29%2B2%29%2F4%29

Comment: In a word, yes.  We can figure out pretty easily that $ \ B \ $ must equal 210º , so $ \ \frac{B}{2} \ $ is 105º.  In fact, the half-angle for an angle in QIII must be in QII, so the cosine value _should_ be negative.  The decimal approximation from a calculator confirms the _exact_ value found from the "half-angle formula" for cosine.

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is in QIII, $\sin B$ and $\cos B$ are both negative. So
\begin{align}
\cos B & = -\sqrt{1-\sin^2 B} & \text{due the identity $\sin^2 B + \cos^2 B = 1$
} \\
&=-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}} & \\
&=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{align}
Also, $\frac{B}{2}$ is in QII, so $\cos \frac{B}{2}$ is negative, and using the identity $\cos^2\frac{t}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos t)$ we get $\cos\frac{B}{2}=-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}[1-(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})]}=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$..

Answer (score 0):

So you have the following:

$$
\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x) = \cos^2(x) - (1 - \cos^2(x)) = 2\cos^2(x) - 1 \\
\cos(x) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos(2x)}{2}} \rightarrow \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos(x)}{2}}
$$

You can find $\cos(B)$ by drawing a picture:

[image: drawing of cos(B)]

This gives:

$$
\cos\left(\frac{B}{2}\right) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{2}} = \pm\frac{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}}}{2}
$$

So should it be plus or minus?  If $\frac{B}{2}$ is in quadrant I, it's positive and if $\frac{B}{2}$ is in quadrant II, it should be negative.  It should be easy to see that $\frac{B}{2}$ must be in quadrant II because if we say we have $0 \leq b \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, then $B = \pi + b$ and $\frac{B}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{b}{2}$.  This puts $\frac{B}{2}$ squarely in the second quadrant (you're adding $90^\circ$ to half of something less than $90^\circ$).  This means:

$$
\cos\left(\frac{B}{2}\right) = -\frac{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{3}}}{2}
$$